# Compile multiple Kernel modules that share code

Tags: c, linux, makefile, module, kernel

I whish to compile two Kernel modules (out of tree) that share a common library : module1.c uses functions from library.c and module2.c also uses functions from library.c. But, library.c implements a global variable "my_variable" that need to be shared between module1.c and module2.c.

For now, I have the following Makefile :

```
# List of files
obj-m   += my_module1.o my_module2.o

my_module1-objs := library.o module1.o
my_module2-objs := library.o module2.o

all:    
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

$(KERNEL_DIR) and $(PWD) are set before makefile is called.

That makefile makes the following output :

```
CC library.o
CC module1.o
LD my_module1.o
CC library.o
CC module2.o
LD my_module2.o
CC my_module1.mod.o
LD my_module1.ko
CC my_module2.mod.o
LD my_module2.ko
```

library.c is compiled twice, for each module that uses it. So there is two different "my_variables" objects that live independently, thing that I want to avoid.

How can I modify the Makefile to first, compile library.c => library.o then use the same library.o to compile each Kernel modules ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to see what is going on exactly.

But from what I can understand you have two separate modules compiling (including the library). Since they are separate they will have their own copy of their variables.

If you want to share a variable you will need to use `EXPORT_SYMBOL` in one module and then `extern` it in the other - something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197345/how-can-i-share-a-global-variable-between-two-linux-kernel-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, shared symbol isn't declared in module1.c or module2.c but in library.c.

If I use `EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_variable);` in library.c and `extern int my_variable;` in libray.h (which is included by both module1.c and module2.c), this results by Warning at compilation :

```
CC library.c
CC module1.c
LD my_module1.o
CC module2.c
LD my_module2.o
WARNNING: my_module2 : 'my_variable' exported twice. Previous export was in my_module1.ko
CC my_module1.mod.o
LD my_module1.ko
CC my_module2.mod.o
LD my_module2.ko
```

At least, library.c is compiled once.

EDIT : Compilation warning has been resolved by moving `EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_variable);` from library.c to module1.c. Thanks !

Comment: Yes that makes sense. If you put the export in the library - then since they both use the library, as you say, it gets exported twice. So you just want to export it in one module and extern it in the other - as it sounds like you have done :)

Comment: Also, for your benefit - you should not add an "answer" as a reply. Its better to add this information to the end of your question (i.e. edit your question and add it to the end) and then use the comment under a specific answer to ask for clarification...