# Is it possible to export a struct symbols?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

in linux kernel driver is it possible to export a struct as a symbol? In other if there are 2 drivers i.e. Driver_A and Driver_B. And Driver_A has a `struct test_a` defined that is required to be exported so that Driver_B can directly reference struct test_a. Something like following

Driver_A has following structure defined

```
    struct test_a { 
       int a, 
       long b, 
       int  (*mem_write)(void *buf_priv, uint32_t size);
    }
    EXPORT_SYMBOL(test_a)
```

Driver_B

```
extern struct test_a test;
```

And method in Driver_B is able to access a,b and

Comment: No, don't think so. A struct type definition is not a symbol (as opposed to a variable of that type). Smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. What is the underlying reason why you think this needs to be done? Why can't the struct be in a common header file?

Comment: I have an use case where I would like to access some methods for Driver_A from Driver_B. Now this can be easily be done via EXPORT_SYMBOLS for a method, but in my use case i would like to assign function pointer at runtime and in future can have same function name defined in another Driver_C.Which will create a conflict if I try to use EXPORT_SYMBOLS on same function name defined in Driver_C. Hence i took approach of exporting struct as a symbol with function pointer as a member.

Comment: Then your example may be wrong and confusing. The example is trying to export a **type definition** whereas it seems you actually want to export a **variable** of that type. The latter should be possible. Have you tried it? If you have a problem with that then suggest you provide the details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share a global variable between two Linux kernel modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197345/how-can-i-share-a-global-variable-between-two-linux-kernel-modules)

Comment: If you use the same global function names in Driver_A and Driver_C, you will only be able to load one of them. I would suggest doing things in a similar way that existing driver modules "register" themselves or some dynamically allocated object with one or more subsystems. For example, drivers for PCI devices register themselves with the PCI subsystem, or drivers for _character special_ files register a set of file operation handlers. Your Driver_A and Driver_C could register themselves with Driver_B.